# Packages reported as missing when they aren't

Tags: tfs, nuget

Suddenly my TFS 2018 private feed has (apparently) started inaccurately reporting the existence of my internal NuGet packages.

VS 2017 is able to read the listing ok, but it complains when I try to install the package:

> Package '<PackageName>' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json,http://server3:8080/tfs/InteXX/_packaging/Packages/nuget/v3/index.json,C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.

But it shows as present in the VS list, as well as the Packages page in TFS. If I knew the folder that TFS uses to store them I could verify, but alas I don't.

This also affects the Updates tab on the VS NuGet dialog; no updates are present there, even though I know I've published them.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes! A solution cleaning was all it took.

Who'da thunk it?

Comment: So, the issue was resolved, right? If it is, then you could mark it as an answer :).

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT: Just did, thanks. SE won't let a person who provides his own answer mark it as such for 48 hours. I was waiting for that window to expire and likely would have forgotten about it, had you not mentioned it.

Comment: This simple issue has cost me way too much time -_-. Thx for the solution!